# React Carousel Boostrap invisble? Probably my fault :D

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

So I tried installed boostrap. Trying to get a carousel showing in my application.
When using React Components on the inspector it seems to see it?

Not showing me any errors, webpack compiled fine

this is App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CarouselAuto from './components/CarouselAuto'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <CarouselAuto/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the component in the component folder named CarouselAuto.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'

const CarouselAuto = () => {
  <Carousel>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
      alt="First slide"
    />
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
      alt="Second slide"
    />

    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
      alt="Third slide"
    />

    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>

}

export default CarouselAuto
```

here is the folder structure
[image]

and this is the result.....

[image]

I am sure its me being a dummy. Its been a long day :D but all help welcome

Answer (score 0):

Content of `CarouselAuto.jsx` should be as follows.

```js
import React from "react";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";

const CarouselAuto = () => (
  <Carousel>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
        alt="First slide"
      />
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
        alt="Second slide"
      />

      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img
        className="d-block w-100"
        src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
        alt="Third slide"
      />

      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
  </Carousel>
);

export default CarouselAuto;
```